# Identify a group of file and process based on a pattern : Python

Tags: python, regex

My requirement is that , if I found a particular pattern in the file name ,then I need to delete the corresponding group of files which belong to that group . For example , below is the group of the files the I have :

```
file1.infile_inprogress_2015033
file1.infile_rsn_20150330022431
file1.infile_err_20150330022431
file2.infile_03_29_2015_05:08:46
file2.infile_03_29_2015_05:09:56
file3.infile_20150330023214
```

The pattern I need to search in a file name is : `"inprogress"` . Hence in the upper list , I will need to delete the following files :

```
file1.infile_inprogress_2015033
file1.infile_rsn_20150330022431
file1.infile_err_20150330022431
```

Because the upper list has the same file name (`"file1"`) before the identifier `"infile"` .

As of now , I could only list the files :

```
 filelist = (glob.glob('C:\\CIRP\\Velocidata\\Test\\*'))
 for file in filelist:
  filenamecopied = os.path.basename(file)
  if fnmatch.fnmatch(filenamecopied,"*Inprogress*"):
   print ('Delete the group of files ')
  else:
   print ('skip this file')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS [walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) is a better bet (easier to read) then filter on the file name.

```
import os
top = 'C:\\CIRP\\Velocidata\\Test\\'

# Getting the list of all files
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):

    # Filtering for group names that are 'Inprogress'
    groups_in_progress = []
    for name in files:
        if 'Inprogress' in name:
            group = name[0:name.lower().find('infile')]
            groups_in_progress.append(group.lower())

    # Delete the files where a group is in progress
    for name in files:
        for group in groups_in_progress:
            if name.lower().startswith(group):
                os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
```

You can use dictionaries and all kinds of optimizations but this is the most straight forward.

Comment: @ Jonathan .. `group = name[0:name.find('.')] ` , instead of "." can I write "infile" and make it case insensitive ? So that it picks up the part "infile" or "Infile" variable ?

Comment: @IshuGupta No No... Accept the answer which you is the best. This is better than mine! (You cannot accept more than 1 answer, you can upvote if you feel it is good)

Answer (score 2):

You need [`os.unlink`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.unlink). From the docs, `os.unlink` is used to

> Remove (**delete**) the file path.

Add a few lines in your `if` clause as

```
# This if will check for "InProgress"
if fnmatch.fnmatch(filenamecopied,"*Inprogress*"):
    filegroup = filenamecopied.split('.')[0]   # get the file group                                                   
    for i in filelist:                         # Iterate through the files
        # This if will check for "file1" or "file2" etc
        if (i.startswith(filegroup)):          # if i is of same group
             os.unlink(i)                      # Delete it
```

Comment: I think the OP is wondering how to delete the *other* files in the group (given that they may have not been iterated over yet, and their precise names may be unknown)

Comment: @DNA But isn't the OP clearly mentioning *I could only list the files*. Doesn't that suffice? :)

Comment: Perhaps - I was just going by the code shown, which has no way to find the related files, only the one matching "inprogress"

Comment: @Bhargav RaoThere are two identifiers , First is "inprogress" which is the first check .
Then there is another one , the group list needs to be decided if the file name matches before "infile" or "Infile"..

Comment: Deletion logic can be applied later , after I zero in to the group of the files .

Comment: @IshuGupta Exactly! That is what I have added. Did you see the edit? If not kindly refresh the page

Comment: Thanks Bhargav , can I split the file name based on "infile" (case insensitive) , as I might have two "." as well in the file name : 
`file1.name1.infile_inprogress_2015033  
file1.name1.Infile_rsn_20150330022431  
file1.name2.infile_err_20150330022431`
In thie example , I would only like to delete the first two as `file1.name1' matches

Comment: @IshuGupta *Sorry*, I live in a different timezone and it was dead in the night here. It is possible but as Jonathan has already beautifully explained. I would just leave this here. Sorry again

Answer (score 1):

A few questions:

1. Are they always in order like you've listed them, or might they pop
   up in different orders?
2. Do they have any regular format features (like filexxx. at the front)?
3. Does the "inprogress" parts always come up before the other files?

If I assume that the file name format is a bunch of letters or numbers then a "." and then a bunch more characters, and that they come up in random order I would do it something like this:

1. Go through creating a list of files prefixes that are going to be deleted.
2. Go through again, deleting files that are in the prefix.

Kind of like this:

```
filelist = (glob.glob('C:\\CIRP\\Velocidata\\Test\\*'))
deleteList = set()
for f in filelist:
    if "inprogress" in f.lower():     #Checks if inprogress is in the filename
        deleteList.add(f[:f.find(".")])  #Adds base of filename
print deleteList
for f in filelist:
    if f[:f.find(".")] in deleteList:
        print "Delete:",f
    else:
        print "Do not delete:",f
```

I haven't done the actual delete code, but you can check whether this is catching everything for you.  I used simple string functions, rather than a re to catch the file names based on what you said.  If not, please post back with answers to above questions!

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... Here are the comments for your questions:  
1)- The files can be in any order.  
2)- They do not have common format in front . The only identifier common in all of them is "infile" which can be "InFile" as well .I need to define the group based on the name before this "Infile" keyword.

Comment: Well, the above should work fine then.  Just replace the "." with "infile", and make sure you use f.lower() to catch the "InFile" type examples.